# Update a list content

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list which can be edited by user and show updated information,I am trying to do postback but i am not able achieve it.
Can someone guide me to achieve it.

My Edit works great,but when i click on Done it should show new edited data. Thanks for help.

Comment: you are using javascript for edit?? how u can say ur edit is working

Comment: Using jquery for edit. Because i can Edit things in div. Js fiddle for edit http://jsfiddle.net/mirinda/wf8yJ/

Comment: you are redirecting control to "Carrer" action of "Home" controller when "Done" is clicked..what things you are getting server side ?

Comment: why your fiddle is not working?

Comment: Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/richasingh/wf8yJ/

Comment: I am not getting any updated content. It is adding new div with no text, instead of updating same.

Comment: Can I see the code of method `UpdateModel()`?

Comment: @Inanikian There is no code for UpdateModel .

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in your `Post Action`? so you will see if it goes to your `if` clause?

Comment: It does go to If clause, but i guess the logic in IF is not right so i am not getting desired output.

Comment: why are u passing 2 models to post method @RS26?? I mean I think you want to update your model with fresh value but in your case mymodel will always return those 2 values that you have assigned in your model class..i hope I am making sence

Comment: Yeah you are. Would you help me with some logic in HttpPost. I want to  show the edited data after done click.  For eg I have original data "Hello how are you"and then i click edit and edit data to "Hello how are you today" it should show "Hello how are you today" refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to do as you wanted for that go through below code

controller :-

```
 public ActionResult Movie()
        {
            MyModel model = new MyModel();
            return View(model);

        }
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Movie(Current mod)
        {
            MyModel car = new MyModel();
            ////if (mod.FormAction.Equals("Done"))
            ////{

                mod.Headers = mod.Headers;
                mod.Ids = mod.Ids;
                mod.Contents = mod.Contents;
                car.Currents.Add(mod);
                UpdateModel(car);
                return View(car);
            ///}

            ////return View();
        }
```

script :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#edit1').click(function () {
        document.getElementById("newpanel1").contentEditable = "true";
        document.getElementById("collapseTwo").contentEditable = "true";

        $('#newpanel1').attr('style', 'border:2px solid;');
        $('#collapseTwo').attr('style', 'border:2px solid;');
        $('#edit1').attr('style', 'display:none;');
        $('#done1').attr('style', 'display:inline:block;');

    });

    $('#done').click(function () {
        document.getElementById("newpanel1").contentEditable = "false";
        document.getElementById("collapseTwo").contentEditable = "false";
        //$("#myContent").val($("#panel1").html());
        $('#newpanel1').attr('style', 'border:none;');
        $('#collapseTwo').attr('style', 'border:none;');
        $('#edit1').attr('style', 'display:block;');
        $('#done1').attr('style', 'display:none;');
         var header = $("#span").html();
            var cars = { Ids: 3, Headers: header, Contents: "sdfsdf" };
            alert(cars.Headers);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/Movie",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(cars),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(lol) {
                    alert(lol);
                }
            });

    });

    $('#delete').click(function () {
        $('#newpanel1').text('');
    })

});
```

View :-

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="panel2">

                    <div class="panel-heading-new">

                        <h4 class="panel-title" id="newpanel1">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" href="#collapseTwo">
                       Title
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                        <a href='#' id="edit1" class="edit-link">Edit</a>
                           <input type="button" value =" done" id ="done"/>

                        <a href='#' class="delete-link" id="delete1">Hide</a>

                    </div>

                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p class="lead justified">
                                Qualifications and Skills:
                            </p>
                            <ul class="fa-ul">

                                <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-hand-o-right pad-icon"></i><span class="lead justified" id="span">Hello</span></li>
                            </ul>
                            <br />
                            <p class="lead justified">Location: Pune</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

fiddle :-

http://jsfiddle.net/wf8yJ/10/

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try and get back to you.:)

Comment: yeah ok sure @RS26 :)

Comment: Thanks for help, but still no luck. It still does not show edited content on refresh. I guess i will have to play around with HTTPPOst code,because the problem is there.

Comment: Yes right. But i read there is way to store temporary data in Session and view it on post back. I know list data won't change, i just want to show edited data using some way.

Comment: sorry I deleted my comment coz it was not useful @RS26 ..got your point

Comment: well you will not get points for upvotes on comments..u will get only if I upvote your question that I have already did @RS26 :)

Comment: Ohh is it, sorry. I am new so don't have ideas.Thanks